# Ban logs in IRC channels, on the example of twitch

Tags: python, sockets, logging, irc, twitch

I am writing a bot in Python + Sockets to collect logs on several twitch channels at the same time. Actually, there are no problems with the messages themselves, but I would like to collect ban / timeout logs for a wider functionality, the code:

```
IRC = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
IRC.connect ((SERVER, PORT))
IRC.send (f "PASS {PASSWORD} \ n" .encode ('utf-8'))
IRC.send (f "NICK {NICKNAME} \ n" .encode ('utf-8'))
IRC.send (f "JOIN {CHANNEL} \ n" .encode ('utf-8'))

while True:
     response = IRC.recv (1024) .decode ('utf-8')
     if response == "PING: tmi.twitch.tv \ r \ n":
         IRC.send ("PONG: tmi.twitch.tv \ r \ n" .encode ('utf-8'))

     print (response)
     time.sleep (.5)
```

In this (yet unfinished) form, he collects messages, but not bans, etc.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered setting up Twitch-IO by chance? If you set up a bot that just connects to your chat and configure logging, it will automatically log to a file, as seen below:

```
from twitchio.ext import commands
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='irclog.txt', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)

bot = commands.Bot(token="irc token", nickname="your username", prefix="doesn't really matter, can be anything", initial_channels=["your channel"])

@bot.event
async def event_ready():
    print("Bot ready, beginning logging")

bot.run()
```

I hope that this was helpful!

Comment: Yes, this is partially what I was looking for, but the question arose, is it possible to find out who banned the user?

Comment: And how can you catch bans? I learned about fetch_ban_events (https://twitchio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=ban#twitchio.PartialUser.fetch_ban_events) from Twitchio's documentation, but I didn’t understand how it works?